# $_FILE is coming across empty

Tags: php, forms, file-upload, web

I am trying to do something that seems very simple. I want to upload a file into a directory on my server using PHP.

This is the form I am using:

```
<form action="getFile.php" method="post"><br>
    Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

Then, after I select a file and submit it, I am doing this in getFile.php:

```
<?php
     var_dump($_FILES);
     var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

And as an output I am getting this:

```
array(0) { } array(1) { ["uploadFile"]=> string(11) "Divider.png" }
```

So the $_FILES array is always empty, but the $_POST is bringing in my filename correctly. I have looked around and saw that write permissions may be an issue. I confirmed that executables were set to write:

[image]

And still no luck. What I am doing doesn't seem overly complicated, but I can't get the $_FILES array to give me anything. It does just get automatically filled from the form, right?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<form action="getFile.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><br>
    Filename: <input type="file" name="uploadFile" id="uploadFile">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File">
</form>
```

You need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"`